# My computer audio is not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I checked my volume several times, I troubleshot my speaker and I could not find any ways to fix it. I restarted my pc even that didn't work. There was a recent windows update I don't know if the update has anything to do with that. If you have any ways to fix it please tell me.

[image: My volume is full]

Comment: You can check if your audio device is set as default. Right click the volume icon at the bottom right corner, and click Playback devices > Check your audio device in the Playback tab. Make sure there is a green check next to your audio device > If your audio device is not the default device, select your audio device, and click Set Default. Then click OK to save. More troubleshooting steps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-sound-problems-in-windows-10-73025246-b61c-40fb-671a-2535c7cd56c8

Answer (score 0):

Your drivers are likely out of date.

Find the Driver Update App from the Support Site for your Computer Manufacturer.

Download and run the App. Update all the drivers it presents to you but make sure the Audio Driver is there and update that along with the others.

If the Updater thinks Audio is current, download the Audio driver from the same location as the Updater App and reinstall the Audio driver.

In less common situations you may also have to update BIOS.  Leave BIOS until you have fully tested reinstalling / updating the Audio Driver.